# Installing intellij plugins on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I was trying to install an SVG Viewer plugin on android studio (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3?pr=idea)

So I went to Settings->Plugins->install from disk.
Then is says in incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

1. I Opened up the zip file with 7z (http://www.7-zip.org/), If its a jar file open it with 7zip
2. (if its a zip file) browsed to lib/[filename].jar
3. browse to "META-INF/plugin.xml" and open the file
4. change since-build="[whatever is here]", to since-build="131"
5. save
6. 7zip will ask you if you want to update the archive -> agree
7. Android studio->Settings->Plugins->install from disk->choose the file

Hope this helps!
**Enjoy**

Comment: 16 minutes ago question, 16 minutes ago answer. That was fast self learning dude ;d

Comment: I posted it as Q&A (one of the options when posting) as I wanted to share the knowledge... is something wrong with that?

Comment: Nah, ofc not. At least for me. Was just saying. Wasnt aware of that option.